# Is there a common way to check in Python if an object is any function type?

Tags: python, types

I have a function in Python which is iterating over the attributes returned from `dir(obj)`, and I want to check to see if any of the objects contained within is a function, method, built-in function, etc.  Normally you could use `callable()` for this, but I don't want to include classes.  The best I've come up with so far is:

```
isinstance(obj, (types.BuiltinFunctionType, types.FunctionType, types.MethodType))
```

Is there a more future-proof way to do this check?

**Edit:** I misspoke before when I said: "Normally you could use `callable()` for this, but I don't want to disqualify classes."  I actually *do* want to disqualify classes.  I want to match *only* functions, not classes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The inspect module has exactly what you want:

```
inspect.isroutine( obj )
```

FYI, the code is:

```
def isroutine(object):
    """Return true if the object is any kind of function or method."""
    return (isbuiltin(object)
            or isfunction(object)
            or ismethod(object)
            or ismethoddescriptor(object))
```

Comment: isroutine() returns False for partials.  hasattr(obj, '__call__') returns True for partials.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to exclude classes and other random objects that may have a `__call__` method, and only check for functions and methods, these three functions in the [`inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-inspect.html)

```
inspect.isfunction(obj)
inspect.isbuiltin(obj)
inspect.ismethod(obj)
```

should do what you want in a future-proof way.

Comment: Upvoted, prefer over hasattr solution because you can define a __call__ item in a user-defined class and hasattr will happily tell you that class has the __call__ attribute, even if it isn't a function.

Comment: I don't see how this is better than the solution in my original comment?  You still have to check for all three explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

```
if hasattr(obj, '__call__'): pass
```

This also fits in better with Python's "duck typing" philosophy, because you don't really care *what* it is, so long as you can call it.

It's worth noting that `callable()` is being removed from Python and is not present in 3.0.

Comment: Worth noting that this will only work for new-style classes.  You get False for old-style classes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by 'class':

```
callable( obj ) and not inspect.isclass( obj )
```

or:

```
callable( obj ) and not isinstance( obj, types.ClassType )
```

For example, results are different for 'dict':

```
>>> callable( dict ) and not inspect.isclass( dict )
False
>>> callable( dict ) and not isinstance( dict, types.ClassType )
True
```