# Check if a built-in function/class/type/module has been over-written during the script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, variable-assignment, built-in

**Question**

We are getting a strange error<sup>**</sup> and we suspect it is because our script.py<sup>***</sup> assigned a variable that already has some built-in meaning. E.g.

```
str = 2
```

Is there a way we can check if this has happened?

---

**So far**

We're thinking it would involve:

1. Assign a list at the beggining of the script, containing all **built-in** objects' names as strings:

   ```
   builtin_names = get_builtin_var_names() # hypothetical function
   ```
2. Assign a list at the end of the script, containing all **user-assigned** objects' names as strings:

   ```
   user_names = get_user_var_names() # hypothetical function
   ```
3. Find the intersection, and check if not empty:

   ```
   overwritten_names = list(set(user_names) & set(builtin_names))

   if overwritten_names:
        print("Whoops")
   ```

---

**Related**

- [Is there a way to tell if a function in JavaScript is getting over
  written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354090/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-a-function-in-javascript-is-getting-over-written)
- [Is there a common way to check in Python if an object
  is any function type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74092/is-there-a-common-way-to-check-in-python-if-an-object-is-any-function-type)

---

<sup>**</sup>**Silent error**, for those interested in it, it is silent, i.e. it finishes without an error code but the value it spits out differs between two implementations of the same code, call them A and B... both versions require the running of two modules (separate files) that we've made (changes.py and dnds.py), but whereas:

- Version A: involves running changes.py -> pickle intermediate data (into a .p file) -> dnds.py,
- Version B: involves running changes.py -> return the data (a dict) as arguments to dnds.py -> dnds.py.

And for some reason only version A is the one with the correct final value (benchmarked against [MATLAB's dnds function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/dnds.html)).

<sup>***</sup>**script.py**, is actually [dnds.py](https://github.com/a1ultima/hpcleap_dnds/blob/master/py/scripts/dnds.py) (who has imported [changes.py](https://github.com/a1ultima/hpcleap_dnds/blob/master/py/scripts/changes.py)). You can find [all the code](https://github.com/a1ultima/hpcleap_dnds), but to test the two alternative versions I was talking about in <sup>**</sup> you need to specifically look at [dnds.py](https://github.com/a1ultima/hpcleap_dnds/blob/master/py/scripts/dnds.py), the line with: CTRL+F: `"#@TODO:Urgent:debug:2016-11-28:"`. Once you find that line, you can read the rest of that comment line for instructions how to replicate version B, and its resulting silent error<sup>**</sup>. For some reason I HAVE to pickle the data to get it to work... when I just return the dicts directly I get the wrong dN/dS values.

Comment: What does the strange error look like?

Comment: Your example is not a great one because `function` is not a builtin name in Python.

Comment: @DaveBensonPhillips, actually it's a silent error. It's simply not giving me the same values as I expect, but if I split my script into separate functions and save the outputs into files as inputs to downstream parts of the script then it works

Comment: @BrenBarn, thanks, I've edited

Comment: Try using regular Python instead of IPython; it looks like IPython does something unusual with `__builtins__`, aliasing it to the name of the module `__builtin__`.

Comment: Try using a linter to catch this

Comment: @Marcin I have actually been using a linter, called sublimelint which I think uses Pylint to lint for the editor Sublime Text 2. It does give me 16 warnings, but I think it's just because I use "# @TODO" in comments or """block comments""" to help me organise my time. I wil check more exhaustively, but right now I'm concerned about why BrenBarn's answer won't even work for me in a fresh IDE

Comment: @BrenBarn I am still getting the same error in the vanilla python interpreter, when pasting line-by-line, or when manually typing, a screen-grab is edited into the question. I have also tried it in an alternative installation of Python (specifically Python 2.7.6 instead of 2.7.3), in an alternative ubuntu partition, and I am still getting the error: "`TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable`"

Comment: @hello_there_andy You may have to turn on specific checks.

Comment: I apologize, it was my own environment that was doing something weird.  I edited my answer with a way that should work, using an explicit `import __builtin__` rather than `__builtins__` (which should not really be used anyway).

Comment: @BrenBarn thanks, it doesn't error now but it seems __name__ and __doc__ are always overwritten, if this is expected then I'll accept, many thanks again

Comment: @hello_there_andy: Yes, those are "special" variables that hold the module name and docstring, so `__builtins__` has its own values.  If you want, you could add an extra `if` check to the loop to exclude those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the names (and values) of builtins via the dict `__builtins__`.  You can get the names (and values) of global variables with `globals()` and of locals with `locals()`.  So you could do something like:

```
import __builtin__
name, val = None, None
for name, val in locals().iteritems():
    if hasattr(__builtin__, name) and getattr(__builtin__, name) != val:
        print("{} was overwritten!".format(name))
```

and then the same for `globals()`.  This will check whether there is any object in the local namespace that has a different value in the builtins namespace.  (Setting `name` and `val` to None is needed so that the variables exist before calling `locals`, or else you'll get a "dictionary changed sized during iteration" error because the names are added partway through the loop.)

You could also use a tool like [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) which checks for such errors among many others.

Comment: Firstly thanks, but I have a conceptual issue with the code you gave, are you sure it's meant to be "!="? Not "=="?

Comment: Actually the code doesn't work at all:

     ```AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'iteritems'```, I am using Python2.7, this was in the tag before your answer but I will make it clear in the question.

Comment: @JonClements cheers, edit is now un-edited, also \*facepalm\* directed at self

Comment: With locals(), I am now getting: ```'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'```

Comment: Yes, I meant `locals()`.  I also made another change to my code.  I can't reproduce the error you're describing.  Please edit your question to include the complete error message.  Are you sure the error you're getting is due to this code, and not due to the original problematic code that you were hoping to debug using this strategy?  The only thing here that I think could potentially cause such an error is `__builtins__[name]`, but it seems unlikely you created your own object called `__builtins__`.

Comment: Ok I have edited the question with the complete error message and just the code of your answer, I did it in IPython and no preceeding code.

Comment: After some lazy testing your answer does seem to work @BrenBarn. At least it managed to catch `str = 2` in an isolated script. Unfortunately for me, it turns out my suspicion was wrong about my actual script... Anyway I will accept the answer since it answers the question. Much thanks for the deliberation you went through.